# Add a column to a delta table in Azure Synapse

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse, delta-lake

I have a delta table that I created in Azure Synapse using a mapping data flow. The data flow reads append-only changes from Dataverse, finds the latest value, and upserts them to the table.

Now, **I'd like to add a column to the delta table**. When you select `Upsert` in a mapping dataflow, the `Merge Schema` is disabled, so it doesn't appear I can use that.

I tried creating a notebook and executing the following SQL, but I get an error.

```
ALTER TABLE delta.`https://xxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/path/to/table` ADD COLUMNS (mytest STRING)
```

> Error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null path

The path provided is not in the default Synapse container.

How can I alter the table and add the column?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was running into was that the default Synapse container wasn't present in the storage account. After creating the container, the command executed successfully.

1. Open Azure Portal
2. Navigate to Synapse Workspace
3. Click Properties
4. Value of `Primary ADLS Gen2 file system`

This helped me track down the issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/706694/unable-to-run-sql-queries-in-azure-synapse-error-o.html